# Помогите правильно объединить строки в html

Tags: php, html

```
    $x=0;
    $y=0;
while ($resilt = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ //пройдемся по циклу
    $x < $resilt; $x++; //номер по порядку
        if ($z==0) //если осталось 0 строк, значит считаем кол-во строк
        {
        $que = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id_kvita) FROM kvitanc WHERE zakryt='1'");//считаем, сколько строк содержит запись
        $re=mysql_fetch_array($que);
        $y=$re[0]; //например 3 раза
        $x=$re[0];
        }
        echo"
            <tr height=28px;>
            <td>{$x})</td>
            <td>{$resilt[1]}</td>
            <td>{$resilt[2]}</td>
            <td>{$resilt[3]}</td>
            <td>{$resilt[4]}</td>
            <td>{$resilt[5]}</td>
            <td>{$resilt[6]}</td>
            <td>{$resilt[7]}</td>
            ";
        if ($y==$z) //если 3 равно 3
        {
            $z=$z-1; //отнимаем единицу
            echo "<td rowspan='".$y."' Редактировать № {$resilt[8]}</td><tr>"; //объединяем 3 ячейки
        }
        elseif ($z!==0) //если 2 не равно нулю
        {
            $z=$z-1; //отнимаем единицу
            echo "<tr>"; //еще одного TD нет, просто новая строка
        }
    }
```

Так вот, при помощи rewspan нужно объединить последнюю колонку, но разметка получается не правильной, объединяет 2 из 3 строк, или 2 из 4...

Comment: Какието очень странные комментарии.

Comment: "id_kvita" - это неуникальный номер, на каждой строке может совпадать, и если он совпадает c предыдущим, тогда идет объединение с предыдущей ячейкой <td></td>. Более умного не смог придумать((

Comment: У вас никогда не закрывается тэг `tr`. В последнем `if` (там где "3 равно 3"), должно быть `</tr>`. Также нехватает `else` ветки. По коду трудно понять, может ли быть такое, что 3 не равно 3 и 2 равно 0, как бы бредово это не звучало.

Comment: Вы гений!)) Я даже не замечал, что tr не закрыт. Закрыл - и все встало на свои места) Ну а отсутствие ветки else для меня значит, что просто выполнять далее не нужно. Или это не есть правильно?

Comment: Ок, тогда создам ответ, про else тамже напишу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас никогда не закрывается тэг `tr`.

В последнем if (там где "3 равно 3"), должно быть `</tr>`, аналогично для `elseif`.

Также нехватает `else` ветки, которая гарантировала бы закрытие `tr`.

К примеру в случае когда `$z` равна нулю а `$y` равна 3, ни последний `if` ни `elseif` не выполнятся, соответственно `tr` не будет закрыта.